# Combination of VMX and Non VMX in multiple CPU's

Tags: x86, virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm, xen

In a dual or multi-CPU configuration, is it possible for one CPU to be operating in VMX mode(root or non-root) and another (or other) CPUs to be executing in legacy (non-VMX) mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if we take kvm as an example:

a VM is a seen as regular linux process, hence it is possible to have one CPU running the VM (VMX mode), and another CPU running another process that has nothing to do with the VM or KVM (hence in non VMX mode)